# Get highest qualifying key suffix from form submission array

Tags: php, arrays, max, text-extraction, suffix

We have a form in which input is added dynamically. From the form submit page, we will get the following result

```
print_r($_POST)

['wind_1']=hk
['wind_2']=pop
etc etc 

['wind_25']=another
```

Here we need to get the last key number, that is **wind_n**, here: **n=25**

> here the last input is ['wind_25'] that's why n=25

Comment: is n is fixed or it is `n > 0`.

Comment: no  , n will dynamic . some time 2 , some time 3 , some time 100 like that

Comment: here the last input is ['wind_25'] that's why n=25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since user supplied data should always be considered untrustworthy, when processing the payload, use strict validation before honoring the array keys. Bear  in mind that the keys might be mutated or reordered without your consent.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TgoPe))

```
$_POST = [
    'wind_1' => 'hk',
    'hamburger_66' => 'foo',
    'wind_2' => 'pop',
    'wind_25' => 'another',
    'wind_13' => 'bar',
    'pass_wind_99' => 'stank',
];

$n = null;
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    if (sscanf($k, 'wind_%d', $windInt) && $windInt > $n) {
        $n = $windInt;
    }
}
var_export($n);
```

Otherwise, it is more succinct and less efficient to use a regex pattern and make three cycles over the array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/T1hgM))

```
var_export(
    (int) max(
        preg_filter(
            '/^wind_(\d+)$/',
            '$1',
            array_keys($_POST)
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

so matching `wind` with key of `$_POST` item if it returns true then take further the count and voila it will give you the very last `wind_n` index.
and also this code will give you the advantage of having some other POST variable in array.

```
 <?php

$_POST = array('wind_1' => 'r','wind_2' => 'r','wind_3' => 'r','wind_4' => 'r');

 $i = 0;
 foreach($_POST as $name => $var){
   if(strpos("wind_",$name) === 0)
   {
     $i++;
   }
 }

echo $i;
```

Comment: This answer doea not extract the numeric suffix from the key,  it merely counts qualifying keys.  This means that in some fringe cases (like when the keys are not in order), this answer will not be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $i=0;
  foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
  {  if(preg_match('/^wind/',$key))
    { $i=$i+1; }  }
 echo $i;
```

here the `foreach` statement accesses all the key-value pair in `$_POST` using `$key` and `$value`. `preg_match()` checks for all the keys that start with wind and for every such key the variable `$i` increments itself. after all the keys are checked, `echo $i` prints the value of `$i` and hence the answer.

Comment: $_POST array will hold some other data than `wind_n` so your code will always give wrong number of wind_n vars count.

Comment: This answer doea not extract the numeric suffix from the key,  it merely counts qualifying keys.  This means that in some fringe cases (like when the keys are not in order), this answer will not be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0;
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
   if(strpos($key,"wind_") == 0) $i++;
}
echo $i;
```

Comment: it will match `qwer-wind_wew` and will give wrong output.

Comment: there is one more chcek needed  if (strpos($key, 'wind_') !== false) { . then it will be okay

Comment: This unexplained answer does not differentiate between `false` and `0` in the loose comparison of `strpos()`'s return value.